# load image which is filtered

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to load the image which is selected in filter. I am not sure how to implement it in javascript.  Should I use the attribute for checking if the selected value is matched with the image attributes? I am not sure how to refer to all the attributes of images. What I would like to achieve is that if selected value is equal to the image attributes, the page only show the selected images.

I saw some people use the event listener of DOMContentLoaded. can someone guide me to implement this?

Here is my html script.

```
    <main>
        
        <!-- filter bar -->
        <div class="filter">
            <label>Filter by Species:
                <select class="species-filter" name="species-filter">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
                    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
                    <option value="rabbit">Rabbit</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <!-- animal photos -->
        <section class="adoption-grid">
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="cat">
                <img src="animal1.jpg" alt="cat">
                <p class="caption">Bailey</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="rabbit">
                <img src="animal2.jpg" alt="rabbit">
                <p class="caption">Vince</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Add more animal cards as needed -->
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="turtle">
                <img src="animal3.jpg" alt="turtle">
                <p class="caption">Fifty</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="cat">
                <img src="animal4.jpg" alt="cat">
                <p class="caption">Timothy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="cat">
                <img src="animal5.jpg" alt="cat">
                <p class="caption">Matty</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal6.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Bella</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal7.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Nancy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal8.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Darlie</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal9.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Windie</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal10.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Puff</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal11.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Jelly</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal12.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Mila</p>
            </div>

            <div class="page-selector">
                <button class="page-button active">1</button>
                <button class="page-button">2</button>
                <button class="page-button">3</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </main>
```

Comment: you say "the image" but you have like 6 dogs - which one?

Comment: load all the selected species. Let say if selected dog, then the page load all the dog images.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

You were right to listen to 'DOMContentLoaded'.

You need to

1. Select the filter element, and animal elements.
2. Listen to select change event
3. Loop through all cards and show/hide them

In your javascript file:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // select filter and animal-cards
    const speciesFilter = document.querySelector('.species-filter');
    const animalCards = document.querySelectorAll('.animal-card');
    
    // event function when you click a filter
    speciesFilter.addEventListener('change', function() {
        const selectedSpecies = speciesFilter.value;
        
        // now loop through all cards and hide/show each
        animalCards.forEach(function(card) {
            const species = card.dataset.species;
           
            if (selectedSpecies === 'all' || selectedSpecies === species) {
                card.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                card.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
   <main>
        
        <!-- filter bar -->
        <div class="filter">
            <label>Filter by Species:
                <select class="species-filter" name="species-filter">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
                    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
                    <option value="rabbit">Rabbit</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <!-- animal photos -->
        <section class="adoption-grid">
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="cat">
                <img src="animal1.jpg" alt="cat">
                <p class="caption">Bailey</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="rabbit">
                <img src="animal2.jpg" alt="rabbit">
                <p class="caption">Vince</p>
            </div>
            <!-- Add more animal cards as needed -->
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="turtle">
                <img src="animal3.jpg" alt="turtle">
                <p class="caption">Fifty</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="cat">
                <img src="animal4.jpg" alt="cat">
                <p class="caption">Timothy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="cat">
                <img src="animal5.jpg" alt="cat">
                <p class="caption">Matty</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal6.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Bella</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal7.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Nancy</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal8.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Darlie</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal9.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Windie</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal10.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Puff</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal11.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Jelly</p>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-card" data-species="dog">
                <img src="animal12.jpg" alt="dog">
                <p class="caption">Mila</p>
            </div>

            <div class="page-selector">
                <button class="page-button active">1</button>
                <button class="page-button">2</button>
                <button class="page-button">3</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </main>
```